# How to return single model value from IEnumerable to pass into partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a list view like

```
@model IEnumerable<EmpDetailsRazor.Models.EmpDetails>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Employee Details";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

**@Html.Partial("_Create", Model);**

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("CREATE NEW","Create")
</p>
```

**list view here**

and I have created a partial view with create 
template with the same model I 
am using in list and I want to call partial view like

```
@Html.Partial("_Create", Model);
```

as it required model like

`EmpDetailsRazor.Models.EmpDetails` rather than 
`IEnumerable<EmpDetailsRazor.Models.EmpDetails>`

how to do this?

Comment: Which item in the collection do you want to pass to the partial? I assume what you really want to do is just `@Html.Partial("_Create", new EmpDetails())`

Answer (score 2):

You can call the Partial using

```
@Html.Partial("_Create", Model.FirstOrDefault())
```

Or if you know there always is at least one item, and you want to make that explicit:

```
@Html.Partial("_Create", Model.First())
```

Note that you may need to add `@using System.Linq` on top to make this work.

Comment: Thanks peter its working fine but i need to empty model as it reloads and that can be done on partial view load with js file